# Resolving System property, clarification needed

Tags: java, system

I have

```
String APP_HOME = System.getenv("APP_HOME") + "/";
String RAW_KVP_HOME = APP_HOME + "reports/raw/";
```

System says

`echo $APP_HOME  --> /path/to/app/home`

**Tests for the project fails.**

Code that fails

```
dbFile = RAW_KVP_HOME + DatastoreUtils.getRandomStringOfLength(8) + ".db";
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + dbFile); // <---- Fails here
```

With

```
java.sql.SQLException: path to 'null/reports/raw/YifQpAPg.db' does not exist
```

I thought that as long as value is set in .profile and is available in shell, `System.getenv("APP_HOME")` should resolve. What am i missing please?

Comment: Could you check if these variables are in `System.getenv()` map when you print it? + Is it `export`ed in the .profile?

Comment: How are you running the code, exactly?

Comment: @dcsohl Code is ran via JUnit test

Comment: @AndreyChaschev hmm .. Yes when I `System.out.println(System.getProperty("APP_HOME"));` I get correct output. This is ran from the same test block that fails.

Comment: @Jam Try `String APP_HOME = System.getProperty("APP_HOME") + '/'`.  If it works, I'll post it as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks reasonable. I would try calling system.getenv without a parameter to get the full mapping then scan through that and see what it contains. Also make sure the environment variable is set globally (or at least in the context where you are executing.)